# Why i keep getting this null data exception although my model class is all string type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Column contains NULL data'.

Could anyone help me please?  I keep getting Column contain null data exception. My model class is all string type, why i get this error?

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

```
[External Code]
LXG.DataAccess.Repository.Repository<T>.GetALL(System.Linq.Expressions
  .Expression<System.Func<T, bool>>, System.Func<System.Linq.IQueryable<T>,
  System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<T>>, string) in Repository.cs
LXG.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CMJobProgController.GetAll() in CMJobProgController.cs
[External Code]
```

PubCode.cs

```
namespace LXG.Models
{
    [Table("PUBCODE", Schema = "LASIS")]
    public class PubCode
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code Type")]
        [Column("CODE_TYPE")]
        public string CodeType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 1")]
        [Column("CODE_1")]
        public string Code1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 2")]
        [Column("CODE_2")]
        public string Code2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 3")]
        [Column("CODE_3")]
        public string Code3 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 4")]
        [Column("CODE_4")]
        public string Code4 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        [Display(Name = "Code ACR")]
        [Column("CODE_ACR")]
        public string CodeACR { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Code Description")]
        [Column("CODE_DESC")]
        public string CodeDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CMJobProgController.cs

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
     //this one no problem
    var allObj = _unitOfWork.cmJobProg.GetALL(j => j.JobNumber == "19950232");

    //this one throws the exception
    var pubcode = _unitOfWork.pubcode.GetALL(s => s.CodeType == "JPA"); 

    return Json(new { data = allObj });
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetALL(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProp);
        }
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Which column? I guess it could have to do with the `[Required]` attributed you seem to have on all columns.

Comment: Yes. I remove the require then it wont have the error.. Cause i retrieve data, the previous data got null. Thanks a lot Jakob Busk Sorensen. I really new to .net core.

Answer (score 0):

you must return to ToList() or FirstOrDefault(). if your field is perimary key that you set FirstOrDefault() if not perimary key set ToList().

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
         var allObj = _unitOfWork.cmJobProg.GetALL(j => j.JobNumber == "19950232").ToList(); //this part must chenge
            var pubcode = _unitOfWork.pubcode.GetALL(s => s.CodeType == "JPA").ToList(); //this part must chenge
                                        
            return Json(new { data = allObj });
        }
```

or you can use other way for gett data from pubcode table
if CodeType is not primary key

```
var pubcode = _unitOfWork.pubcode.Where(s => s.CodeType == "JPA").ToList();
```

if CodeType is primary key

```
var pubcode = _unitOfWork.pubcode.Where(s => s.CodeType == "JPA").FirstOrDefault();
```